# Intersection of the sum of a sequence of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $\{x_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \in H$ and $\{y_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \in H$ be two basic sequences in $H$

Let $X_m = \overline{\operatorname{span}} \{x_p\}_{p \geq m}$

Let $Y_m = \overline{\operatorname{span}} \{y_p\}_{p \geq m}$

We know that there is an isomorphism $T : \overline{\operatorname{span}} \{x_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \to \overline{\operatorname{span}} \{y_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $Tx_m = y_m$

Is it true that:

$$
\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty
\left( X_m + Y_m \right)
=\{0\}
$$

Thanks.

Comment: Are $x_i$ linearly independent?

Comment: @Berci yes they are linearly independent

Comment: If $x_m\to x\ne 0$, then $x+Tx$ is in the intersection. Let e.g. $x_m=(1, \frac12, \dots, \frac1m, 0, 0,\dots) $ in $\ell_2$.

Comment: @Berci in your e.g is $x_m$ a basic sequence ?

Comment: As much a basis as $(1,0,0, \dots), \ (0,1,0,\dots), \ (0,0,1,\dots), \ \dots$

Comment: @Berci please can you give me the proof that your $x_m$ is a basic sequence ?